# Выдаёт ошибку в mysql (Status Server)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysqlconnector

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А После выдаёт это
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я уже всё перепробывал и даже этот PATH добавлял в system32, но всё напрасно, прошу помогите мне с данной проблемой
И из-за этого я наверное не могу подключить Visual Studio WindowsForms к SQL

Comment: Точно не отвечу, но ответ комментарий "даже этот PATH добавлял в system32" меня напрягает. Вообще-то первый экран просит system32 в PATH добавить. Советую дать в вопросе ссылку на ресурс, согласно которому вы прописывали этот путь в PATH окружения, а также команды, которыми вы это сделали.

Comment: Метка sql-server зачем?

Comment: @Сергей мне почему-то кажется, что system32 априори в path находится

Comment: попробуйте от имени администратора запустить софтину.

Comment: @teran, я этого просто не знаю. Я - искусственный интеллект,  использую формально-логический подход. На первой картинке сказано в этом убедиться. А вот добавлять PATH в него не просили.

Answer (score 0):

Для решения данной проблемы достаточно скопировать 2 файла:

```
c:\Windows\SysWOW64\chcp.com
c:\Windows\SysWOW64\ulib.dll
```

в папку с программой оболочки сервера

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0
```